# How to connect processes via pipe in Perl?

Tags: bash, perl, pipe

I want to write a Perl script which runs the programs `foo` and `bar` and processes `stdout` of `foo` and emits it to `stdin` of `bar` in a streaming fashion. The Perl script should act like this `bash` command:

```
$ foo | some-perl-code | bar
```

I managed to do the first part with the snippet below. I start the program `foo` and open the pipe to read `stdout`.

```
open( my $pipe_fh, "foo |" );
while ( my $row = <$pipe_fh> ) {
   # do stuff
    print $row;
}
```

How can I realize the second part? How can I emit `$row` to the program `bar` *within* my Perl script?

Comment: Why does this have to be in a Perl scrip? Why can't you use bash directly?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just use another open, but revert the direction of the pipe:

```
open my $in,  '-|', 'foo' or die $!;
open my $out, '|-', 'bar' or die $!;
while ( my $row = <$in> ) {
    # do stuff
    print {$out} $row;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Another option is using [IPC::Pipeline](https://metacpan.org/pod/IPC::Pipeline) to chain the processes together instead of doing it manually.

Answer (score 0):

[IPC::Run](https://metacpan.org/pod/IPC::Run) is also another (somewhat daunting) option.  If you end up with complex pipelines, may I also recommend (shameless promotion of own module) [IPC::PrettyPipe](https://metacpan.org/pod/IPC::PrettyPipe), which I wrote to help render complex pipelines.

Comment: Wow, I did not know about `IPC::Run`. I think this removes the last reason why I'd ever write a shell script and not a perl script!